# Retrieve user role and group from jboss container using JAAS API CALL

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, jaas

In my current project, I have a scenario where user will login into portal and authenticated via TAM(Tivoli).  After login into portal there will be a link from which user will be redirected to our application (spring mvc) hosted on JBOSS. 
Now the information we have is, user role and group info will be available within our container and we have to make JAAS api call to retrieve user roles and group info which further will be used by spring security for authorization purpose.
I can imagine that this will be a spring  pre-authentication scenario where user will already been authenticated (SSO) and for authorization we need  to retrieve his role and group info .
Could you please assist me to correct my  understanding and how to get those user role/group from JBOSS container using JAAS API?
Any code snippet or link (spring implementation) will be helpful.
Thanks,
CD

Comment: Were you actually able to get this done? I am trying to sort of do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to create a SSO structure, isn't the Spring documentation useful enough?

You can find the SSO part here: [Spring Security Reference: Chapter 9](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-sso.html)

What ApplicationServer are you using? Can you do a more specific question on some implementation instead?